# Looking for input to a simple transformative Ab initio molecular dynamics (AIMD) trajectory simulation

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, software, molecular-dynamics, density-functional-theory

I'm looking for a simple Ab initio molecular dynamics (AIMD) simulation of some small molecular system that I can run myself on a desktop computer. I want a molecular system that actually changes somewhat during the simulation, it doesn't have to be big changes at all, but just something other than a bunch of water molecules moving among themselves with the system essentially the same at all times. The simulation doesn't have to be run with the most accurate potentials, but should on the other hand be a somewhat reasonable approximation.

I have been looking for days and have tried asking in a bunch of places, but so far I haven't found anything, any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

I'm looking to simulate the MD system in [CP2K](https://www.cp2k.org/), and I want to let it run for 10k-500k steps.

background information: I have a background in physics, but not really molecular dynamics, and I'm currently in machine learning which is what I will be needing this dataset for. I need to be able to generate the dataset myself since I need some rather unique pieces of information from the dataset at each iteration that are normally not available.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? I see what you're trying to accomplish, but I don't see what question you have...

Comment: I'm asking whether anyone who is in the field of MD have done any simulation that would fit the above criteria or knows of any simulation like that, and if so could point me towards a paper or preferably some input files that would enable me to run such a simulation.
It could also just be something along the lines of: "You should try to run a NVT simulation of aspirin at 800K for about 200 ps, and then you should see it change from one configuration to another"